# White spaces before and post equal sign, brackets and other

Tags: visual-studio-2012, equals, brackets

I use Visual studio 2012 and plugin Visual assist X ver. 1916. I have two questions.

**1)** When I write equal sign (`=`), I want automatic insertion of white spaces before and after the sign (I must always insert by space on keyboard...). Is it possible?

Example:

```
int variable=167;
->
int variable = 167;
```

or

```
"=" -> " = "
```

**2)** I want automatic insertion of white space before and after brackets and before and after commas. Is it possible?

Example:

```
void fun(int param1,int param2);
->
void fun ( int param1, int param2 );
```

Comment: Your English is fine :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: `white space before and after brackets` Yuck :(

Answer (score 0):

VASSISTX -> Tools -> Edit VA Snippets.
Add new one with shortcut `"="`(without the "") and in the body write `" = "`(without the ""). Same goes for the rest of your requirements, the rule is simple: in shortcut write the symbol you want to be identified when typed and in the body what you actually want to be printed.

Comment: but this only work when i have one space after name variable than I see list where i find equal sign...

Comment: Yep, that's the best I could find. But at least you save typing of the trailing space :)